# Can I turn off inline syntax checking in the Office 2003 VBA editor?

Tags: vba

As anybody who uses VBA in Office 2003 will know, it has the extremely frustrating tendency to do a syntax check every time you click off a line.

For example, if I start writing a line of code, I might go

```
For Each application In
```

And then think "crap, what's the application collection called?" So I'll hit "page up" to find it, and get (in this case) a "Compile Error".

Can I turn this off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Goto Tools-> Options  and turn off 'Auto Syntax check'. While you're there, turn on 'Require variable declaration':

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a9f473f5d0.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/a9f473f5d0.jpg)